# Can we somehow use the functor $\mathbf{Set}(\mathbb{N},-)$ to define $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: category-theory

Hom functors can be used define coproducts in terms of products. In particular:

$$\mathbf{Set}(A \sqcup B,X) \cong \mathbf{Set}(A,X) \times \mathbf{Set}(B,X)$$

To oversimplify a little: "a function out of $A \sqcup B$ is the same thing as a function out of $A$ and a function out of $B$." I was wondering if we can do something similar for $\mathbb{N}$. So basically, we're trying describe not $\mathbb{N}$, but rather, the functor $\mathbf{Set}(\mathbb{N},-).$

Now $\mathbb{N}$ can be described as the initial pointed monounary algebra, meaning its the initial set $X$ together with a distinguished element of $X \times \mathrm{End}(X)$. That means there's a distinguished function $\nu_X$ associated to each set $X$ of the following type:

$$\nu_X : X \times \mathrm{End}(X) \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}(\mathbb{N},X)$$

But this won't usually be an injection; because, two different pointed monounary algebra structures on a set $X$ can induced the same function $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$, despite behaving differently on the complement of the subalgebra generated by the basepoint.

It usually won't be a surjection, either; for instance, if $x$ and $y$ are distinct elements of $X$, then the function $$(x,x,y,y,y,\ldots) : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$$ fails to be in the image of $\nu_X$.

So at this point, I'm feeling a little stuck.

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: You need to ask that the function $\mathbb N \to X$ sends the $0$ to the selected point of $X$. In that case $\nu_\cdot$ becomes a natural bijection. This is precisely the universal property of a [natural number object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object#CCC).

Comment: No, that's not quite true. You also need the function to commute with the chosen endomorphisms.

Comment: um, $\nu_X$ is not surjective, right ?

Comment: @mercio, that's also true.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It's not clear to me what kind of characterization you want. The reason you can define coproducts in terms of products the way you do is because 1) the category of representable functors of a locally small category $\mathcal C$ is literally the opposite category $\mathcal C^{op}$ and 2) you can compute limits pointwise in the category of representable functors. So an object satisfies a property if and only if its representable functor satisfies the opposite property, and then it's a question of expressing the opposite property in some more convenient way. Is that what you want?

Comment: @VladimirSotirov, I think so. Something like that.